# SELECT a string as a date in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, date

I have a mysql table which stores the date in string format and i want to select the date as datetime. I tried it both with STR_TO_DATE() and DATE_FORMAT it didn't work.

My date is saved like 02/10/2013 00:00 what i want is to select this string as date so that i can use comparison.

Here is what i tried:

```
SELECT meta_value  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d/%M/%Y %H:%i' ) > NOW() AND meta_key='project_end'
```

For some reason STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d/%M/%Y %H:%i' ) returns NULL. If anyone can figure out whats the problem then that would be great.

Comment: Next time use the proper data format for your data.

Comment: No, actually its wordpress and its postmeta table so that i can't modify the data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%M` (capital letter m) is the month name (ie, May/October/etc). Try using `%m` instead, eg:

```
SELECT meta_value  
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(meta_value,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i' ) > NOW() 
AND meta_key='project_end'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that now i got the solution. It would be %m/%d/%Y %H:%i as my string is like 02/10/2013 00:00